# WhereHas trying get specific column without his child

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to display recommended discounts by the views they got.
And show them with the business logo and business name, and query them by cities and categories chosen by the user.

Discount is the child of Business
and when I make the requests I'm getting the discount and inside it the business and inside the business the discounts he has, which I don't need again

```
   public function recommendations(Request $request)
   {
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'categories' => 'array',
        'cities' => 'array'
    ]);

    $query = Discount::whereHas('business', function($innerQuery) use ($fields) {
        if ($fields['cities']) {
            $innerQuery->whereJsonContains('cities', $fields['cities'])
                ->orWhereNull('cities');
        }
        if ($fields['categories']) {
            $innerQuery->whereJsonContains('categories', $fields['categories'])
                ->orWhereNull('categories');
        }

    })
    ->with('business:id,logo')
    ->orderBy('views','desc');
    
    return $query->paginate(18);
}
```

the results I'm getting
[API results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLoMl.png)

Im trying to remove the discounts nested inside the business.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: please provide `Discount` and `Business` models and relations, its very likely that in `Business` model defined default eager loading or customized relation in `Discount` model (check if there is `protected $with = [...];` code)

Comment: hey, thanks for answering me so fast, there is protected with but its with orders.

Comment: if you want blind luck try to remove pagination and see if it helps. other parts must be working fine

Comment: Try that, no luck :(
I've been found something pretty weird, I have in business model appends='total_points'
when I remove it I don't see the discounts.
but there is no connection between those two.
the problem is that I need that total_points, is there a way to remove the appends there?